# Opensource Graphics Framework for Web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, graphics, drawing

Is there any opensource HTML5+CSS3+Javascript based Graphics framework (like www.degrafa.org) available to help one develop an online drawing tool like the one provided by lucidcharts.com?

I basically want to develop a tool where a user can drag-and-drop some already available shapes, resize, rotate, and perform other operations on the figures drawn.

Suggestion for flash based opensource frameworks are welcome too. :)

Answer (score 2):

Dragging and dropping shapes would not be a problem (check out EaseJS). I'm sure you **aren't** expecting some primitive shapes to be shipped with the library, but are looking to code up the programmatic definitions of primitives, and utilize the drag and drop features of the framework. I hope my assumption is correct. Even if the underlying framework does not provide drag and drop wrappers out of the box, they should not be difficult to code. So here goes:

### JS

- **EaseJS (with a drag and drop demo!)**
- http://easeljs.com/examples/dragAndDrop.html
- **RaphaelJS**
- http://raphaeljs.com/
- **Processing.js**
- http://processingjs.org/

### Actionscript

- **X-Graphics Drawing Framework**
- http://code.google.com/p/xgraphics-drawing-framework/
- **ASDraw**
- http://code.google.com/p/asdraw/
- **Graffiti**
- http://www.nocircleno.com/graffiti/

Comment: That's right. I don't need the framework to come with pre-built images. Infact, I will want to embed my custome shapes into the tool. And use different user-interaction capabilities, provided by the framework, on those shapes.

Answer (score 1):

Another great framework is d3.js

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/